# MVC5 Code First model is missing AspNetUserRoles

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

I just generated code first model from existing database in which I have asp.net identity 2.0 tables. From what I can see, the AspNetUserRoles cs file is missing although I've selected the table when I was creating the model.

Did anyone else stumble with this problem while generating the code first model from existing database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is `IdentityUserRole`, but it won't exist anywhere in your code since it's part of the Entity Framework Identity code.